# JBoss 7.1 final register spring module

Tags: spring, jboss, osgi, osgi-bundle

i want to register org.springframework.context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar as module in my JBoss 7.1 server but i get this error while enabling it: http://pastie.org/5381730

```
11:45:44,423 ERROR [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.FrameworkEventsPlugin] (MSC service thread 1-8) Framework ERROR: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Cannot resolve bundle resModule: [org.springf
ramework.context:3.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.ResolverPlugin.resolve(ResolverPlugin.java:157) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.AbstractBundleState.ensureResolved(AbstractBundleState.java:551) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState.startInternal(HostBundleState.java:211) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.AbstractBundleState.start(AbstractBundleState.java:494) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.osgi.deployment.BundleStartTracker$1.processService(BundleStartTracker.java:144) [jboss-as-osgi-service-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.osgi.deployment.BundleStartTracker$1.transition(BundleStartTracker.java:119) [jboss-as-osgi-service-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.invokeListener(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1416) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$2700(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ListenerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1954) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: org.jboss.osgi.resolver.XResolverException: Unable to resolve Module[org.springframework.context:3.0.2.RELEASE]: missing requirement [Module[org.springframework.context:3.0.2.RELEASE]] pack
age; (&(package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=3.0.2)(!(version>=3.0.3)))
        at org.jboss.osgi.resolver.felix.FelixResolver.resolveInternal(FelixResolver.java:117) [jbosgi-resolver-felix-1.0.13.Final.jar:1.0.13.Final]
        at org.jboss.osgi.resolver.spi.AbstractResolver.resolve(AbstractResolver.java:149) [jbosgi-resolver-spi-1.0.13.Final.jar:1.0.13.Final]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.ResolverPlugin.resolve(ResolverPlugin.java:155) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        ... 11 more

11:45:44,443 ERROR [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011900: Cannot start bundle: org.springframework.context:3.0.2.RELEASE: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Cannot resolve bundle: o
rg.springframework.context:3.0.2.RELEASE
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState.startInternal(HostBundleState.java:212) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.AbstractBundleState.start(AbstractBundleState.java:494) [jbosgi-framework-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.osgi.deployment.BundleStartTracker$1.processService(BundleStartTracker.java:144) [jboss-as-osgi-service-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.osgi.deployment.BundleStartTracker$1.transition(BundleStartTracker.java:119) [jboss-as-osgi-service-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.invokeListener(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1416) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$2700(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ListenerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1954) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]

11:45:44,443 ERROR [org.springframework.context] (Thread-67) FrameworkEvent ERROR: org.apache.felix.log.LogException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Cannot resolve bundle resModule: [org.springfr
amework.context:3.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.ResolverPlugin.resolve(ResolverPlugin.java:157)
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.AbstractBundleState.ensureResolved(AbstractBundleState.java:551)
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.HostBundleState.startInternal(HostBundleState.java:211)
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.AbstractBundleState.start(AbstractBundleState.java:494)
        at org.jboss.as.osgi.deployment.BundleStartTracker$1.processService(BundleStartTracker.java:144)
        at org.jboss.as.osgi.deployment.BundleStartTracker$1.transition(BundleStartTracker.java:119)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.invokeListener(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1416)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.access$2700(ServiceControllerImpl.java:49)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ListenerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1954)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: org.apache.felix.log.LogException: org.jboss.osgi.resolver.XResolverException: Unable to resolve Module[org.springframework.context:3.0.2.RELEASE]: missing requirement [Module[org.springfra
mework.context:3.0.2.RELEASE]] package; (&(package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=3.0.2)(!(version>=3.0.3)))
        at org.jboss.osgi.resolver.felix.FelixResolver.resolveInternal(FelixResolver.java:117)
        at org.jboss.osgi.resolver.spi.AbstractResolver.resolve(AbstractResolver.java:149)
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.ResolverPlugin.resolve(ResolverPlugin.java:155)
        ... 11 more

11:45:44,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 6) JBAS018559: Deployed "org.springframework.context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar"
11:46:14,314 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015892: Deployment unit processor org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor@66a91604 unexpectedly threw a
n exception during undeploy phase INSTALL of deployment "org.springframework.context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar": java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.allDeploymentModuleClassLoaders(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:138)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.undeploy(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:122)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.safeUndeploy(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:167) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.stop(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:161) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.stopService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1911) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1874) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
```

what exactly is wrong i'm not sure. but im importing many .jar files in the jboss management deployments and only some of the spring libraries failed to start and the error is not clear, something with osgi.

Comment: The NullPointerException on undeploy had been fixed in JBoss 7.1.2 - https://community.jboss.org/thread/198957. But that will still not solve your problem. It appears the OSGI dependencies are not resolved in your bundle. Can you explain how you setup your Spring module in JBoss?

Comment: i just register them as module :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but after i add com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar as registered module other spring libraries work without error.

Comment: commons-logging 1.1.1 was a dependency that was not resolvable earlier. If you remove it once than you will get the same error.